# "Member of" or "member of the"

Tags: articles

1. Member of the Polaris Scientific student circle.
2. Member of Polaris Scientific student circle.

First, is there any difference b/w the use of "member of" and "member of the"?

Second, if I'm not using a name, saying for example "electronics" instead of "Polaris", how does this affect the use of the article?

Comment: Actually, I think it depends on whether or not "student circle" is part of the name. "I'm a member of Electronics Scientific *Student Circle*." "I'm a member of the Electronics Scientific *student circle*." "I'm a member of *a scientific electronics student circle*."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote from [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/why-there-is-the-before-some-names-but-not-others):

> We use proper nouns for any institution or establishment where part of the name is a noun denoting the kind of institution or establishment.

**student circle** is a compound noun describing the institution or establishment, and so the definite article **the** is required.

> Member of the Polaris Scientific student circle.

Judging by the fact that the sentence doesn't contain a subject or verb, for example "I am a ..", this looks like something that you might put on your CV. For lists of information like entries on a CV, it is acceptable to omit articles where the meaning is clear.